Flutter fetch certain child after equalTo
I want to retrieve data from Google Firebase RTDB.
My Current Structure in RTDB is like this:
"organization"
- 2024-05 (yearMonth)
--- organizationId
------ audits
----------- audit_id
-------------score
-------------location_id

So the score and location_id are on the same level, under certain audit_id
Here's my current query code:
    DataSnapshot auditData = await auditRef
        .child(yearMonth)
        .child(currentActiveOrganizationID)
        .child("audits")
        .orderByChild('location_id')
        .equalTo(locationID)
        .get();

    if (auditData.value != null) {
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> auditMap = auditData.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
      List auditMapKey = auditMap.keys.toList();
      int score = auditMap[auditMapKey[0]]['score'];
      return score;
    } else {
      return null;
    }

I want to get the audit score, but from this query, I have to fetch all of the other data under the audit_id such as "audited_by", "audited_at"
How to make it more simple?

There is no way to just return a single property of the node with your query without modifying the data model. The Firebase Realtime Database API always returns complete nodes.
So if you want to only retrieve the score, create an additional node in your database where you only keep the score for each location_id with just the properties you need.
